# How to return HTML page from RestController in Spring?

Tags: java, html, spring, spring-boot, rest

I'm learning Spring and Rest web services so this is little bit confusing to me.
This is my class:

```
RestController
@RequestMapping("/app-api/users")
public class UserApiController {

 @Autowired
 UserRepository userRepo;

 @GetMapping
 public Iterable<User> getUsers(){
    return userRepo.findAll();
  }   
}
```

Now when i test this `GET` request in some rest client i get `HTTP status 200` and all users in `JSON` format. But how can i display them in `HTML`? I tried this like regular controller:

```
@GetMapping("/test")
public String getUsers(Model model) {
    Iterable<User> users = userRepo.findAll();
    model.addAttribute("users", users);

    return "test-user";
}
```

But this doesn't work since it just return `test-user` as regular text. My question is what is proper way and convention for manipulating data from `RestController` and displaying them in html?

Comment: You would need to return a complete HTML document and set the media-type to `text/html` (`@GetMapping("/test", produces = javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType.TEXT_HTML)`)

Comment: @Turing85 i'm getting 404 error.

Comment: Are you passing the correct parameters to getUsers(Model mode) method? Are you accessing the correct URL(app-api/users/test)? Are you facing the 404 error in browser or restclient?

Answer (score 0):

Spring Web services are usually used to present an API who provide raw data for stand alone applications (e.g. angular, mobile app)  to use,  it can be confusing at first.

If you want your application to provide HTML page i recommand you take a look at [ThymeLeaf](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-crud-thymeleaf) i guess there is other ways to do the same thing but its the only one i know. Hope that helps, have a nice day !

Comment: I have Thymeleaf in my project but i'm still getting an error. What should i do?

Answer (score 0):

Your

```
@GetMapping("/test")
public String getUsers(Model model) {
  model.addAttribute("users", userRepo.findAll());
  return "test-user";
}
```

should go to `@Controller` annotated class (not @RestController).

And

```
@GetMapping
public Iterable<User> getUsers(){
  return userRepo.findAll();
}
```

to another `@RestController` class.

Those are two different approaches.
You use @Controller to form HTML page on server side using one of template engines (like mentioned Thymeleaf).
While @RestController is for API endpoint. You would typically use javascript to make an ajax request and form HTML on client side.

Comment: Thanks for replying, is that how developers usually handle rest controllers? To form HTML page we must make an ajax request on client side?

Comment: Rest controllers is for API, where P stands for Programming. You need some program to request rest controllers. This may be javascript ajax (typically for building html) or any other program.
You can use one of two approaches or mixture of both.
Using rest controllers and some js library/framework like React.js is more advanced technique, but for simple stuff using ordinary controllers and server side rendering is ok.